Displaying layers using WFS in ArcMap
I have connected to a WFS feed in ArcMap 10.7.1 using Interoperability Connections but when I drag the layers from the WFS list onto my map/contents it displays the following error:

Error Reading Interoperability Data. The dataset appears to be
invalid. Please verify that your setting or file contents are correct
and try again.

The WFS layer list also displays each layer twice, with the second of each suffixed with "NoGeometry".
My connection parameters look like this:

The WFS connection works well in QGIS and ArcGIS Pro but I have some customers who need to use it in ArcMap.
Is there a parameter I am missing?
I wondered about Max Features but have played around with it and changing that has not worked.
